# How to model a ruffles that actually attaches to a piece of clothing

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I was wondering how I can make something that looks like this in blender and some wrinkles on clothes that have less triangles/verts. Thank you for your help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe switch to *Sculpt* mode and use the *Cloth* brush. In the *N panel > Tool > Deformation >* choose *Pinch Perpendicular*. Use the *Mask* brush if you want some parts not be affected:

[image]